# Comparing values of a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to iterate over a list of dictionaries and check every Quantity key and compare the values and then print/display the Dictionary with the highest quantity value.

For example. This is my list of dictionaries. I have multiple keys and values and I want to compare the Quantity Values of each Dictionary.
I then want to display only the Dictionary that has the highest value.

shoe_list = [{'Country': 'South Africa', 'Code': 'SKU44386', 'Product': 'Air Max 90', 'Cost': '2300', 'Quantity': '20'}, {'Country': 'China', 'Code': 'SKU90000', 'Product': 'Jordan 1', 'Cost': '3200', 'Quantity': '50'}, {'Country': 'Vietnam', 'Code': 'SKU63221', 'Product': 'Blazer', 'Cost': '1700', 'Quantity': '19'}, {'Country': 'United States', 'Code': 'SKU29077', 'Product': 'Cortez', 'Cost': '970', 'Quantity': '60'}, {'Country': 'Russia', 'Code': 'SKU89999', 'Product': 'Air Force 1', 'Cost': '2000', 'Quantity': '43'}, {'Country': 'Australia', 'Code': 'SKU57443', 'Product': 'Waffle Racer', 'Cost': '2700', 'Quantity': '4'}, {'Country': 'Canada', 'Code': 'SKU68677', 'Product': 'Air Max 97', 'Cost': '3600', 'Quantity': '13'}, {'Country': 'Egypt', 'Code': 'SKU19888', 'Product': 'Dunk SB', 'Cost': '1500', 'Quantity': '26'}, {'Country': 'Britain', 'Code': 'SKU76000', 'Product': 'Kobe 4', 'Cost': '3400', 'Quantity': '32'}, {'Country': 'France', 'Code': 'SKU84500', 'Product': 'Pegasus', 'Cost': '2490', 'Quantity': '28'}, {'Country': 'Zimbabwe', 'Code': 'SKU20207', 'Product': 'Air Presto', 'Cost': '2999', 'Quantity': '7'}, {'Country': 'Morocco', 'Code': 'SKU77744', 'Product': 'Challenge Court', 'Cost': '1450', 'Quantity': '11'}, {'Country': 'Israel', 'Code': 'SKU29888', 'Product': 'Air Zoom Generation', 'Cost': '2680', 'Quantity': '6'}, {'Country': 'Uganda', 'Code': 'SKU33000', 'Product': 'Flyknit Racer', 'Cost': '4900', 'Quantity': '9'}, {'Country': 'Pakistan', 'Code': 'SKU77999', 'Product': 'Air Yeezy 2', 'Cost': '4389', 'Quantity': '67'}, {'Country': 'Brazil', 'Code': 'SKU44600', 'Product': 'Air Jordan 11', 'Cost': '3870', 'Quantity': '24'}, {'Country': 'Columbia', 'Code': 'SKU87500', 'Product': 'Air Huarache', 'Cost': '2683', 'Quantity': '8'}, {'Country': 'India', 'Code': 'SKU38773', 'Product': 'Air Max 1', 'Cost': '1900', 'Quantity': '29'}, {'Country': 'Vietnam', 'Code': 'SKU95000', 'Product': 'Air Mag', 'Cost': '2000', 'Quantity': '2'}, {'Country': 'Israel', 'Code': 'SKU79084', 'Product': 'Air Foamposite', 'Cost': '2430', 'Quantity': '4'}, {'Country': 'China', 'Code': 'SKU93222', 'Product': 'Air Stab', 'Cost': '1630', 'Quantity': '10'}, {'Country': 'South Korea', 'Code': 'SKU66734', 'Product': 'Hyperdunk', 'Cost': '1899', 'Quantity': '7'}, {'Country': 'Australia', 'Code': 'SKU71827', 'Product': 'Zoom Hyperfuse', 'Cost': '1400', 'Quantity': '15'}, {'Country': 'France', 'Code': 'SKU20394', 'Product': 'Eric Koston 1', 'Cost': '2322', 'Quantity': '17'}]

max_quantity = max(shoe_list, key=lambda x: x['Quantity'])
print(max_quantity)

output:

{'Country': 'Uganda', 'Code': 'SKU33000', 'Product': 'Flyknit Racer', 'Cost': '4900', 'Quantity': '9'}

This is the output I get when I try the above code.

Comment: Can you please attach the code you have tried? Also a sample dictionary would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python built-in function [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with a custom function that will provide a custom key for item comparison in your list:

```python
list_of_dicts = [{'Country': 'China', 'Code': 'BHK234', 'Product': 'Nike Air','Price': '1245', 'Quantity': '12'}, {'Country': 'South Africa', 'Code': 'BAK274', 'Product': 'Nike Air 1','Price': '1945', 'Quantity': '34'}]
print(max(list_of_dicts, key=lambda x: int(x['Quantity'])))
```

will ouput

```
{'Country': 'South Africa', 'Code': 'BAK274', 'Product': 'Nike Air 1', 'Price': '1945', 'Quantity': '34'}
```

Comment: Paste your code, without it it's hard to understand what's the problem

Comment: Oh, I missed that you store Quantity as string. So you also need to convert string to integer before comparison. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
products = [{'Country': 'China', 'Code': 'BHK234', 'Product': 'Nike Air','Price': '1245', 'Quantity': '12'}, {'Country': 'South Africa', 'Code': 'BAK274', 'Product': 'Nike Air 1','Price': '1945', 'Quantity': '34'}]

quantities = [i["Quantity"] for i in products]
print(products[quantities.index(max(quantities))])
```

To get the highest quantity value from a list of dictionaries, you can just iterate through the list, collect the quantities, get the index of the highest value and use that to get the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example  with your code

```
list_of_dict.sort(key=lambda x: x['Quantity'], reverse=True)
max_dicts = [d for d in list_of_dict if d['Quantity'] == list_of_dict[0]['Quantity']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep you maximum price dict in one of the variable, then iterate over the list once and update value if price is more.
You can use the following code.

```
highestValueDict = List_of_dict[0]
for dic in List_of_dict:
    if dic['Price'] > highestValueDict['Price']:
        highestValueDict=dic
print(highestValueDict)
```